# Does JFace ListViewer support tooltips?

Tags: swt, jface

Can I set tooltips for items in a ListViewer? Or Do I need to use a single-column TableViewer instead if I want them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only implementation of [`ToolTip`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/window/ToolTip.html) that comes with Eclipse and provides tooltips based on contents of the viewer/control is [`ColumnViewerToolTipSupport`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.html) that expects `ColumnViewer`. It will probably be easier to use `TableViewer`, but it's not too complicated to implement your own tooltip support for list viewer.

Comment: How would you go about implementing your own toolTip?